# how do I add an indicator to display lm-sensors information?

Tags: 12.04, indicator, sensors

I want to be able to see how hot my system is from the indicator menu, kind of like [speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) does it on windows.

I remember doing this some time ago in ubuntu, but can't figure it out now. Using 12.04.

Comment: You will find an answer to your question in this answer : http://askubuntu.com/a/48288/22537

Comment: Take a look over there **http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-display-network-upload-download.html**. Works great and can be customized to display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy.Just type `CPU Temp` in `Synaptic` and install the one you like most.

Comment: I could only find one, but it worked out. Psensor for anyone else looking though this